# Why is my site blank when I add HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mayur's Personal Site</title>

    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #eaf6f6;
        }
        hr{
            background-color: white;
            border-style: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    
    <img src="mayurrr.png" alt="mayuresh profile picture">
    <h1>Mayuresh Bhosale</h1>
    <p><i><strong> Student of <a href="https://www.sanjivanicoe.org.in/">Sanjivani College of Engineering, Kopargaon.</a> </strong></i></p>
    
    <p>Hi I am Mayuresh from Aurangabad. I am pursuing my B.tech from Sanjivani College of Engineering, Kopargaon.
         <br>I am learning Web Development from udemy.</p>
    <hr>
    
    <h3>Education</h3>

        
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>School/College</th>
            </thead>
           
            <tr>
                <td>2007-2017</td>
                <td>Maharashtra Public School, Aurangabad</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2017-2019</td>
                <td>Sarosh Junior College, Aurangabad</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2019</td>
                <td>Sanjivani College of Engineering, Kopargaon</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    
    <hr>
    <h3>Hobbies</h3>
    <ol type="I">
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/i.mayuresh.__/">Photography</a> </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.riotgames.com/en">Playing Games</a> </li>
        <li><a href="hobbies.html">Listening to Music</a> </li>
    </ol>
    <p><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></p>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code!
If I try to add table and in that one row then website gets blank.This same happened when I tried to add background colour to horizontal rule in style tag. Did anyone faced same problem when learning HTML and css?
Now I have added exact same code which is not executing properly.

Comment: In order for somebody to actually be of assistance to you, you'll have to show the code with which you're trying to add that table and style rule.

Comment: hr{
            background-color: white;
            border-style: none;
        }
this is it

Comment: Your `hr { ... }` CSS rule has nothing to do with this -> `If I try to add table and in that one row`. You'll need to tell us what that last thing means, and show the code that you built `to add table and in that one row`.

Comment: @Mayuresh Please, post the code not here in the comments, but as an edit to your question as it will be easier to follow by everybody.

Comment: Now I have added exact same code which is not executing properly.

Comment: double </body> as well

Comment: Run your code through https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input until you have no errors

Comment: @Mayuresh please insert a code snippet, I want to see if it shows as blank on my computer

Comment: I noticed that you're ending the body tag twice, maybe this is the issue?

Comment: It's working just fine in the SO code snippet editor. Check your computers storage capacity, I remember this happening to me once too.

Comment: Yes!! body tag was twice, it's running fine now.
Thank you

Comment: I put it as an answer as well, glad I could help... @Mayuresh

Comment: Sure thing! It was just a little problem.
thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible reasons for a code to run blank on a computer. In some cases it might be because you haven't closed `<body>` or `</head>` tags properly (or maybe you have duplicates). In other cases however, it might have to do with your computers storage capacity. Check if your storage capacity says something like "0 bytes available" or a very low number. If this is the case you can clean up system files and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Your `table` is inside a `ul` element, and it's the only child element of that `ul`. That's invalid HTML. A `ul` has to contain `li` elements.

Just erase the `ul` opening and closing tag.

Comment: tried this but when adding hr{ background-color: white; border-style: none; } adding this to style again its getting blank : (

Comment: That UL element is no longer in the question. Not sure why.